# Vector space $V\cong \mathbb R^n$ or $\cong \mathbb C^n$.

Tags: vector-spaces

I was wondering something, Let $V$ a $\mathbb R-$vector space and $W$ a $\mathbb C-$vector space both of dimension $n$. Is it true that $$V\cong \mathbb R^n\quad  \text{and}\quad W\cong \mathbb C^n\ \ ?$$ 
I don't know, it seems natural for me, so I would say yes. I'm asking the question just to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. More generally, if $E$ and $F$ are both $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces of dimension $n$ then $E \simeq F$.

Comment: Maybe it is worth to add that this isomorphism is not canonical and this is why people use the notation $V$ instead of simply $\mathbb{K}^n$.